# How to restore my certificates at /etc/ssl/certs?

Tags: 18.04, ssl, openssl, certificates

Suddenly my /etc/ssl/cert directory is almost empty and I have no idea how it happened.
[image]

there were about 400 (symbolic links) left yesterday.

Lots of things don't work any more (including apt package manager) because of missing certs.

Running `sudo ca-update-certificates` produces a very weird output:

```
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
find: ‘test’: file or directory not found
find: ‘test’: file or directory not found
find: ‘test’: file or directory not found
... 127 times same message
127 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...

updates of cacerts keystore disabled.
done.
```

Where should a test folder or file be?
What can I do to resolve my issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not found the reason for the weird issues, but reinstalling the core-utils

```
sudo apt install --reinstall coreutils
```

solved my issues.